# Non standard ZCL package support for CC253x firmware

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, texas-instruments, zigbee

My problem is:

Livolo switches have their own Zigbee gate. I want to connect them from zigbee2mqtt with CC2531 USB dongle. In general it works, but when I turn on/off switch button (on physical device), the switch sends an incorrect ZCL package.

I'm an absolutely newbie in microcontrollers programming and in Zigbee architecture. So I hope someone can help me and answer these questions:

- Where I can intercept that malformed package?
- How I can fix that package to support the Zigbee standard?

I use  Z-STACK-HOME 1.2.2a firmware and compile it as described there:
https://github.com/Koenkk/Z-Stack-firmware/blob/master/coordinator/Z-Stack_Home_1.2/COMPILE.md

> ```
> // Malformed ZCL package
> // header    
> 0x7c, // [0111 1100]
>       // 01 - frame type = "Command is specific or local to a cluster"
>       // 1 - manufacturer spec = manufacturer code present
>       // 1 - direction = "from server to client"
>       // 1 - disable default response 
>       // 100 - reserved
>
> 0xd2, 0x15, // manufacturer  
> 0xd8, // sequence  
> 0x00, // read attrs command
>
> // endpoint adress 
> 0x12, 0x0f, 0x05, 0x18, 0x00, 0x4b, 0x12, 0x00, 
>
> 0x22, 0x00, // ????? need more data from another switches
>
> 0x03 // 0x00|0x01|0x02|0x03 - switch state
> ```

upd:
I think, what I can intercept message in AF.c file in afIncomingData function and fix in afBuildMSGIncoming.

So now I hope, someone can help me with the right message format. Which can be processed standard ZCL parcer.

```
void afIncomingData( aps_FrameFormat_t *aff, zAddrType_t *SrcAddress, uint16 SrcPanId,
                     NLDE_Signal_t *sig, uint8 nwkSeqNum, uint8 SecurityUse,
                     uint32 timestamp, uint8 radius )
{
  endPointDesc_t *epDesc = NULL;
  epList_t *pList = epList;
#if !defined ( APS_NO_GROUPS )
  uint8 grpEp = APS_GROUPS_EP_NOT_FOUND;
#endif

  if ( ((aff->FrmCtrl & APS_DELIVERYMODE_MASK) == APS_FC_DM_GROUP) )
  {
#if !defined ( APS_NO_GROUPS )
    // Find the first endpoint for this group
    grpEp = aps_FindGroupForEndpoint( aff->GroupID, APS_GROUPS_FIND_FIRST );
    if ( grpEp == APS_GROUPS_EP_NOT_FOUND ) {
      // No endpoint found, default to endpoint 1.
      // In the original source code there is a return here. 
      // This prevent the messags from being forwarded.
      // For our use-case we want to capture all messages. 
      // Even if the coordinator is not in the group.
      epDesc = afFindEndPointDesc( 1 );
    }
    else {
      epDesc = afFindEndPointDesc( grpEp );
    }

    if ( epDesc == NULL )
      return;   // Endpoint descriptor not found

    pList = afFindEndPointDescList( epDesc->endPoint );
#else
    return; // Not supported
#endif
  }
  else if ( aff->DstEndPoint == AF_BROADCAST_ENDPOINT )
  {
    // Set the list
    if ( pList != NULL )
    {
      epDesc = pList->epDesc;
    }
  }
  else if ( aff->DstEndPoint == 10 || aff->DstEndPoint == 11 ) {
    if ( (epDesc = afFindEndPointDesc( 1 )) )
    {
      pList = afFindEndPointDescList( epDesc->endPoint );
    }
  }
  else if ( (epDesc = afFindEndPointDesc( aff->DstEndPoint )) )
  {
    pList = afFindEndPointDescList( epDesc->endPoint );
  }

  while ( epDesc )
  {
    uint16 epProfileID = 0xFFFE;  // Invalid Profile ID

    if ( pList->pfnDescCB )
    {
      uint16 *pID = (uint16 *)(pList->pfnDescCB(
                                 AF_DESCRIPTOR_PROFILE_ID, epDesc->endPoint ));
      if ( pID )
      {
        epProfileID = *pID;
        osal_mem_free( pID );
      }
    }
    else if ( epDesc->simpleDesc )
    {
      epProfileID = epDesc->simpleDesc->AppProfId;
    }

    // First part of verification is to make sure that:
    // the local Endpoint ProfileID matches the received ProfileID OR
    // the message is specifically send to ZDO (this excludes the broadcast endpoint) OR
    // if the Wildcard ProfileID is received the message should not be sent to ZDO endpoint
    if ( (aff->ProfileID == epProfileID) ||
         ((epDesc->endPoint == ZDO_EP) && (aff->ProfileID == ZDO_PROFILE_ID)) ||
         ((epDesc->endPoint != ZDO_EP) && ( aff->ProfileID == ZDO_WILDCARD_PROFILE_ID )) )
    {
      // Save original endpoint
      uint8 endpoint = aff->DstEndPoint;

      // overwrite with descriptor's endpoint
      aff->DstEndPoint = epDesc->endPoint;

      afBuildMSGIncoming( aff, epDesc, SrcAddress, SrcPanId, sig,
                         nwkSeqNum, SecurityUse, timestamp, radius );

      // Restore with original endpoint
      aff->DstEndPoint = endpoint;
    }

    if ( ((aff->FrmCtrl & APS_DELIVERYMODE_MASK) == APS_FC_DM_GROUP) )
    {
#if !defined ( APS_NO_GROUPS )
      // Find the next endpoint for this group
      grpEp = aps_FindGroupForEndpoint( aff->GroupID, grpEp );
      if ( grpEp == APS_GROUPS_EP_NOT_FOUND )
        return;   // No endpoint found

      epDesc = afFindEndPointDesc( grpEp );
      if ( epDesc == NULL )
        return;   // Endpoint descriptor not found

      pList = afFindEndPointDescList( epDesc->endPoint );
#else
      return;
#endif
    }
    else if ( aff->DstEndPoint == AF_BROADCAST_ENDPOINT )
    {
      pList = pList->nextDesc;
      if ( pList )
        epDesc = pList->epDesc;
      else
        epDesc = NULL;
    }
    else
      epDesc = NULL;
  }
}

static void afBuildMSGIncoming( aps_FrameFormat_t *aff, endPointDesc_t *epDesc,
                 zAddrType_t *SrcAddress, uint16 SrcPanId, NLDE_Signal_t *sig,
                 uint8 nwkSeqNum, uint8 SecurityUse, uint32 timestamp, uint8 radius )
{
  afIncomingMSGPacket_t *MSGpkt;
  const uint8 len = sizeof( afIncomingMSGPacket_t ) + aff->asduLength;
  uint8 *asdu = aff->asdu;
  MSGpkt = (afIncomingMSGPacket_t *)osal_msg_allocate( len );

  if ( MSGpkt == NULL )
  {
    return;
  }

  MSGpkt->hdr.event = AF_INCOMING_MSG_CMD;
  MSGpkt->groupId = aff->GroupID;
  MSGpkt->clusterId = aff->ClusterID;
  afCopyAddress( &MSGpkt->srcAddr, SrcAddress );
  MSGpkt->srcAddr.endPoint = aff->SrcEndPoint;
  MSGpkt->endPoint = epDesc->endPoint;
  MSGpkt->wasBroadcast = aff->wasBroadcast;
  MSGpkt->LinkQuality = sig->LinkQuality;
  MSGpkt->correlation = sig->correlation;
  MSGpkt->rssi = sig->rssi;
  MSGpkt->SecurityUse = SecurityUse;
  MSGpkt->timestamp = timestamp;
  MSGpkt->nwkSeqNum = nwkSeqNum;
  MSGpkt->macSrcAddr = aff->macSrcAddr;
  MSGpkt->macDestAddr = aff->macDestAddr;
  MSGpkt->srcAddr.panId = SrcPanId;
  MSGpkt->cmd.TransSeqNumber = 0;
  MSGpkt->cmd.DataLength = aff->asduLength;
  MSGpkt->radius = radius;

  if ( MSGpkt->cmd.DataLength )
  {
    MSGpkt->cmd.Data = (uint8 *)(MSGpkt + 1);
    osal_memcpy( MSGpkt->cmd.Data, asdu, MSGpkt->cmd.DataLength );
  }
  else
  {
    MSGpkt->cmd.Data = NULL;
  }

#if defined ( MT_AF_CB_FUNC )
  // If ZDO or SAPI have registered for this endpoint, dont intercept it here
  if (AFCB_CHECK(CB_ID_AF_DATA_IND, *(epDesc->task_id)))
  {
    MT_AfIncomingMsg( (void *)MSGpkt );
    // Release the memory.
    osal_msg_deallocate( (void *)MSGpkt );
  }
  else
#endif
  {
    // Send message through task message.
    osal_msg_send( *(epDesc->task_id), (uint8 *)MSGpkt );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the whole malformed frame that you get - I mean including the APS layer if possible?

Comment: Unfortunatly, now I reflashed my dongle what I used as sniffer, and has not enough examples, one is APS header = 00 08 01 00 04 01 06 ba.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [AF.c](https://gist.github.com/komelgman/101b2415da2e6f1eb035b25da2085b6c) file in functions afIncomingData and afBuildMSGIncoming added bloks marked by

```
#if defined ( LIVOLO_SUPPORT ) 
#endif
```

In afIncomingData I add:

```
#if defined ( LIVOLO_SUPPORT )  
  else if ( aff->DstEndPoint == 0x08 ) 
  {
    if ( (epDesc = afFindEndPointDesc( 1 )) )
    {
      pList = afFindEndPointDescList( epDesc->endPoint );
    }
  }  
#endif
```

It's prewent filtering message sended to unknown destEndpoint

And in afBuildMSGIncoming function:

```
#if defined ( LIVOLO_SUPPORT )
  uint8 fixedPackage[] = { 
        0x18, 0xd8, 0x01, // header
        0x00, 0x00, // attrId
        0x00, // success
        0x10, // boolean
        0x00
      };

  if (aff->SrcEndPoint == 0x06 && aff->DstEndPoint == 0x01 
      && aff->ClusterID == 0x0001 && aff->ProfileID == 0x0104) {

    const uint8 mlfrmdHdr[] = { 0x7c, 0xd2, 0x15, 0xd8, 0x00 }; 
    if (osal_memcmp(asdu, mlfrmdHdr, 5) == TRUE) {      
      fixedPackage[7] = asdu[aff->asduLength - 1];
      MSGpkt->cmd.DataLength = 8; // sizeof(fixedPackage)
      MSGpkt->clusterId = 0x06; // genOnOff
      asdu = fixedPackage;
    }
  }
#endif
```

It change unsupported package to readAttrResp package.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you're decoding the frame control byte correctly.  Looking at some code I've written, I interpret it as follows:

```
0x7c, // [0111 1100]
      // 011 - reserved
      // 1 - disable default response 
      // 1 - direction = "from server to client"
      // 1 - manufacturer spec = manufacturer code present
      // 00 - frame type = "Command acts across entire profile"
```

This is based on an old ZCL spec (around 2008?) and perhaps the reserved bits have taken on some meaning in a later version of the spec.

I believe the manufacturer specific bit indicates that this is **not** a standard Zigbee command (Read Attributes).  If it was Read Attributes, I think it should have an even number of bytes following it (16-bit attribute IDs).

What were the source and destination endpoints, profile ID and cluster ID for that frame?

Update:
It looks like you could modify `afIncomingData()` to look at the fields of `aff` to identify this exact message type (frame control, endpoints, cluster, profile), and then hand it off to your own function for processing (and responding if necessary).

But I'd also take a look at documentation for `MT_AF_CB_FUNC` and `MT_AfIncomingMsg()` to see if that's the "official" way to identify frames that you want to handle in your own code.

Comment: APS frame looks like: 00 08 01 00 04 01 06 ba. Dest endpoint 08; Src endpoint 06; Cluster id 00 01; profile id 01 04; thanks

Comment: APS frame *header

Comment: What message I should send instead this non standard message? Thanks